# Control-Tab stuck in search box

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

When Command-Tab(bing) through Notes, the cursor gets stuck in the search field and I cannot seem to get it out?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Hello, thanks... Esc, Ctrl-Shift-Tab... looks like **Tab** does this trick.